# How to check if a Map is also a Struct?

Tags: elixir

In Elixir I can check if a variable is a `map` or a `struct`, by calling [`Kernel.is_map/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#is_map/1) which makes sense because [Structs are Maps underneath](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html#structs-are-bare-maps-underneath), but I'd like to differentiate between the two. I know that I can call `__struct__` on a Struct to get it's module name but calling it on a normal map throws:

```elixir
** (KeyError) key :__struct__ not found in: %{}
```

So my question is, **How do I check if a variable is a map or a struct?**

---

**Example use case:**

```elixir
# I want to handle struct and map inputs differently in my Module

defmodule DifferentThings do
  def do_something(arg) when is_map(arg) do
    # Do something with Maps
  end

  def do_something(arg) when is_struct(arg) do
    # But handle Structs differently
    # Issue is, `is_struct` does not exist
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the simplest way to check if a term is a `map` is to use:

```ex
Map.has_key?(map, :__struct__)
```

It does not work in a guard so we had to previously resort to pattern match the `:__struct__` key in the function clause:

```ex
def some_fun(%__struct__: _module}), do: ...
```

But this just plain looks dirty.

---

## Guard: `is_struct/1`

Starting in Erlang/OTP 21, a couple of new guards were introduced that we can use to define our own:

```ex
defguard is_struct(term) when is_map(term) and :erlang.is_map_key(:__struct__, term)
defguard is_struct(term, module) when is_struct(term) and :erlang.map_get(:__struct__, term) == module
```

Now you can use them as function guards:

```ex
def do_something(account) when is_struct(account, User) do
  # Do something with %User{} structs
end

def do_something(struct) when is_struct(struct) do
  # Do something with random structs
end

def do_something(map) when is_map(map) do
  # Do something with maps
end
```

---

<sup>***Note:** These will soon be added to Elixir standard library itself. Follow the discussion in this [ElixirForum thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/discussion-incorporating-erlang-otp-21-map-guards-in-elixir/14816?u=sheharyarn).*</sup>

Answer (score 28):

In general to check if map is a struct:

```
Map.has_key?(struct, :__struct__)
```

For different method declarations (more general method is second):

```
defmodule DifferentThings do
  def do_something(%{__struct__: _} = arg) do
    # ...
  end

  def do_something(arg) when is_map(arg) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: If you need pattern match can use `%{__struct__: _} = struct`

Comment: I tried to use this but get compiler warnings: "warning: key :__struct__ is ignored when using structs".  Granted, I'm on an old version of elixir -- 1.8.2. I could swear I've done just this in the past in more recent elixirs but perhaps I'm mis-remembering :)

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to pattern match between struct and map like below

```
defmodule DifferentThings do
  def do_something(arg = %_x{}) do
    IO.puts "This is a struct"
  end

  def do_something(arg = %{}) do
    IO.puts "This is a map"
  end
end
```

Comment: Liked the `arg = %_x{}` very much, but you can do also `arg = %_{}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have separate function heads for Map vs Struct with a guard, but you can do it with pattern matching.

```
defmodule Guard do

  def foo(%{:__struct__ => x })  do
    Struct
  end

  def foo(x) when is_map x do
    Map
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check easily `keys` of current map with `Map.keys/1`.

For both map and struct `is_map/1` will return true, but in your example:

```
Map.keys(%{}) will return []
```

and

```
Map.keys(struct)
```

will return collection of keys, eg. `[:__struct__, :name, :age]`.

So you can simply use:

```
:__struct__ in Map.keys(struct).
```

If you want to have this `is_struct` make it macro then.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: `Map.has_key?(struct, :__struct__)`

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants - That's much better. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As [Sheharyar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533054/sheharyar) noted, [Elixir 1.10.0](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.10.0) introduces the [`is_struct/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.10.0/Kernel.html#is_struct/1) guard. Therfore, your original code will work.